# JS jQuery on change get innerHTML of select option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, innerhtml

I know how to get the "value" of a selected option tag on change of the select dropdown. But how do I get the associated "text" i.e. inner HTML into the JS variable "country_name" ?

```
<select name="country" class="country">
    <option value="please-select" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">select country</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="ES">Spain</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="IT">Italy</option>
</select>

<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('select.country').on('change',function(){
    var country_code = $(this).val();
    var country_name = 'Selected Country Name';
    alert(country_code+" - "+country_name);
});
</script>
```

Desired alert output for for instance the second option:

ES - Spain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to build a selector relative to the dropdown, reaching into its `option` children and filtering to just the selected one, via jQuery's `:selected` pseudo-selector:

```
var country_name = $(this).children(':selected').text();
```

Comment: If I add that, it gives me me the output: "ES - [object Object]"

Comment: Sorry, wrote in a rush; see edit - you need the `.text()` method.

Answer (score 3):

to get the selected text of the selected option of a select field I would do the following

```
$("select.country").change(function(){
    var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected");
    var country_code = selectedCountry.val();
    var country_name = selectedCountry.text();
    alert(country_code+" - "+country_name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in you javascript

```
$('select.country').on('change',function(){
var country_code = $(this).val();
var country_name = ( $(this).find(":selected").text() )

alert(country_code+" - "+country_name);
});
```